# Unit Tests for async code (indexedDB) inside React Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to write unit tests for a React component - That looks something broadly as follows -

1. a handle to a db is passed to a component
2. The component also receives `data` as `props` (that will change) - perhaps this is something that could come through a Redux store.
3. Now what I do in my `useEffect` for this `data` change is - Write into `indexDB` (actually using the `idb` library) and then on `success`, I read some of this data and setup a local state using `setData` and use this state to `render`

Basically all of the above works - so there is no problem with that (It's perhaps not right, but works!). My challenge is how to write unit test for this code. I have looked at using `async` inside `jest`.

The code looks something like as follows -

```js
const Component = ({db, data}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const saveDataToDB = (data, successCB) => {
       const tx = db.transaction("store", "readwrite");
       
       const transactions = [tx.store.add(data)];
       transactions.push(tx.done);
  
       Promise.all(transactions).then((res) => {
          successCB();
       });
       
      const cb = () => {
          // Do somethingl
       }; 
       
       saveDataToDb(data, cb);

    };

  }, [data]);

   // Rendering part. 
   return (
     <div id="component-div">


     </div>


   );


};

export default Component;
```

and I am trying to write the tests for this component using something like following

```js
describe('Component Tests', () => {
  
  it("Component Renders with Data", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Component data={data} db={db}/>);
    expect(wrapper.find("#component-div").toEqual(true);

  });


});
```

May be - there's something wrong the way component is implemented, that makes unit testing challenging. But it works, so not sure in general about what's the strategy for unit testing components that could have a few promise chains to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

[react testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) has support for [async APIs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async). They can be used to achieve to solve the problem mentioned above.

This would require converting the test cases to `async` test cases and then `await`ing using right the `async` APIs as described above.

The original test cases mention `enzyme` APIs, instead of that `react-testing-library` APIs are to be used.